# how to get the slope of a linear regression line using c++?

Tags: c++, math, linear-regression

I need to attain the slope of a linear regression similar to the way the Excel function in the below link is implemented:

```
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/slope-function-HP010342903.aspx
```

Is there a library in C++ or a simple coded solution someone has created which can do this?

I have implemented code according to this formula, however it does not always give me the correct results (taken from here http://easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-regression.php) ....

```
Slope(b) = (NΣXY - (ΣX)(ΣY)) / (NΣX2 - (ΣX)2)
         = ((5)*(1159.7)-(311)*(18.6))/((5)*(19359)-(311)2)
         = (5798.5 - 5784.6)/(96795 - 96721)
         = 13.9/74
         = 0.19
```

If I try it against the following vectors, I get the wrong results (I should be expecting 0.305556):
    x = 6,5,11,7,5,4,4
    y = 2,3,9,1,8,7,5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What slope result did you get?  Copying the slope calculation without the original data doesn't help too much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why don't you just write a simple code like this (not the best solution, for sure, just an example based on the help article):

```
double slope(const vector<double>& x, const vector<double>& y){
    if(x.size() != y.size()){
        throw exception("...");
    }
    size_t n = x.size();

    double avgX = accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0.0) / n;
    double avgY = accumulate(y.begin(), y.end(), 0.0) / n;

    double numerator = 0.0;
    double denominator = 0.0;

    for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i){
        numerator += (x[i] - avgX) * (y[i] - avgY);
        denominator += (x[i] - avgX) * (x[i] - avgX);
    }

    if(denominator == 0.0){
        throw exception("...");
    }

    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Note that the third argument of accumulate function must be 0.0 rather than 0, otherwise the compiler will deduct its type as `int` and there are great chances that the result of accumulate calls will be wrong (it's actually wrong using MSVC2010 and mingw-w64 when passing 0 as the third parameter).

Comment: thanks! Looks like it is working, i will need to give it a few more thorough tests mind you!

Comment: i have noticed you throw an exception if the sizes are not equal, in my scenario i might have two buffers of unequal size, if this is the case can i just assign n with the smallest size of the two?

Comment: @Schiavini Totally agree, too much C# will kill me ^_^ Corrected the code.

Comment: When denominator==0, does it mean that all x values are the same, so the slope is infinite?

Comment: @Schiavini Well, i think it could be considered in different ways depending on the system logic, I posted just a sample on how to do stuff like that, polishing is on the OP.

Comment: I tried your algorithm and the output was wrong. I'm pretty sure your formula is incorrect. You need to use innerproduct()

Answer (score 27):

Here is a C++11 implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

double slope(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y) {
    const auto n    = x.size();
    const auto s_x  = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0.0);
    const auto s_y  = std::accumulate(y.begin(), y.end(), 0.0);
    const auto s_xx = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), 0.0);
    const auto s_xy = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0.0);
    const auto a    = (n * s_xy - s_x * s_y) / (n * s_xx - s_x * s_x);
    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> x{6, 5, 11, 7, 5, 4, 4};
    std::vector<double> y{2, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7, 5};
    std::cout << slope(x, y) << '\n';  // outputs 0.305556
}
```

You can add a test for the mathematical requirements (`x.size() == y.size()` and `x` is not constant) or, as the code above, assume that the user will take care of that.

Comment: thanks, what if x and y were not the same size? In my scenario this is a possibility, can i simply assign n the value of the one with the smallest size?

Comment: @godzilla: `n = min(x.size(), y.size())` doesn't work here because `accumulate` doesn't stop after `n` elements. It stops when the container has been completed parsed. (Similar issue for `inner_product`.)

Comment: agreed - but speaking generally regarding slopes, if one vector is larger than the other can i simply just set n to the minimum (not using accumulate of course) and sum up both vectors up until N only?

Comment: @godzilla: Yes, you can.

Comment: is the slope in radians?

Comment: @spaceman The slope is not the angle but its tangent. For instance, the slope of the line y = x is 1 because the angle theta between this line and the x-axis is 45 degrees (or pi/4 radians) and tan(theta) = 1. In general, the slope of y = a*x is a.

Comment: @CassioNeri can you tell me which study material did you use to learn this formula for the slope?

Comment: @spaceman This is pretty much classic and I've just joined the dots between math formulas and C++ constructs. On the math side, search for "Linear Regression" and "Least Squares". On the C++ side, look for good C++ (library) references (e.g. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/))). I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank You

Answer (score 7):

The following is a templatized function I use for linear regression (fitting). It takes std::vector for data

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> GetLinearFit(const std::vector<T>& data)
{
    T xSum = 0, ySum = 0, xxSum = 0, xySum = 0, slope, intercept;
    std::vector<T> xData;
    for (long i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        xData.push_back(static_cast<T>(i));
    }
    for (long i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        xSum += xData[i];
        ySum += data[i];
        xxSum += xData[i] * xData[i];
        xySum += xData[i] * data[i];
    }
    slope = (data.size() * xySum - xSum * ySum) / (data.size() * xxSum - xSum * xSum);
    intercept = (ySum - slope * xSum) / data.size();
    std::vector<T> res;
    res.push_back(slope);
    res.push_back(intercept);
    return res;
}
```

The function returns a vector with the first element being the slope, and the second element being the intercept of your linear regression.

Example to use it:

```
std::vector<double> myData;
myData.push_back(1);
myData.push_back(3);
myData.push_back(4);
myData.push_back(2);
myData.push_back(5);

std::vector<double> linearReg = GetLinearFit(myData);
double slope = linearReg[0];
double intercept = linearReg[1];
```

Notice that the function presumes you have a series of numbers for your x-axis (which is what I needed). You may change that in the function if you wish.

Comment: Did you take a look at the other guy's answer? I think his formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a similar function, but I needed it to handle a bunch of near-vertical slopes.  I started out with Cassio Neri's code and then modified it to recalculate slopes that appear to be steeper than 1 after mirroring each point around the line x=y (which can be done easily by switching the x and y values).  Then it will mirror it back and return a more accurate slope.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

double slope(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y) {

    const double n     = x.size();
    const double s_x   = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0.0);
    const double s_y   = std::accumulate(y.begin(), y.end(), 0.0);
    const double s_xx  = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), 0.0);
    const double s_xy  = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0.0);
    const double numer = n * s_xy - s_x * s_y;  // The same regardless of inversion (both terms here are commutative)
    const double denom = n * s_xx - s_x * s_x;  // Will change if inverted; use this for now
    double       a;

    if (denom == 0) a = 2;  // If slope is vertical, force variable inversion calculation
    else a = numer / denom;

    if (std::abs(a) > 1) {  // Redo with variable inversion if slope is steeper than 1
        const double s_yy = std::inner_product(y.begin(), y.end(), y.begin(), 0.0);
        const double new_denom = n * s_yy - s_y * s_y;
        a = new_denom / numer;  // Invert the fraction because we've mirrored it around x=y
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> x{6, 5, 11, 7, 5, 4, 4};
    std::vector<double> y{2, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7, 5};
    std::cout << slope(x, y) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This formula is wrong. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/effect-of-switching-response-and-explanatory-variable-in-simple-linear-regressio